Синонимия и оттенки значений (продолжение темы о структуре словарной статьи)
Этот вопрос был задан в  теме среди других вопросов, но его скорее надо рассматривать отдельно.
Но что такое «оттенок значения» не понятно, нет нигде определения «оттенка 
 значения». Более того, есть мнение, что это размытое понятие у которого 
 вообще научного определения в лингвистике не существует.

Не существует научного определения? Может быть, тогда не стоит задавать подобный вопрос в рамках форума, где требуются короткие ответы, если уж лингвисты с этим не справляются.
Но я все-таки задам его еще раз хотя бы для того, чтобы обозначить проблему, а также дам ответ по одному из источников в Сети.


ТЕОРИЯ

ЗНАЧЕНИЕ И ОТТЕНОК ЗНАЧЕНИЯ (из ресура  Studfile.net)
Другой семантической величиной, меньшей значения, является оттенок значения, о котором ведутся длительные споры в отечественном и зарубежном языковедении.
Ученые отмечают объективные трудности его изучения, обусловленные самой природой таких идеальных образований: они потенциальны, подвижны, требуют для своей актуализации и оживления наличия особых контекста, речевых условий.
Оттенок функционирует внутри понятия, в пределах его логической схемы, не затрагивая категориальных функций значения слова; он более индивидуален, ассоциативен, а потому нередко потенциален, т. е. реализуется далеко не в каждом употреблении слова, в значение которого он входит.
Синонимия сама по себе не является условием существования оттенков значения. Это семантически независимые явления; оттенки формируются, существуют и могут обнаруживаться и вне синонимических отношений.
Оттенки значения, не выходя за рамки одного и того же понятия, могут подчеркивать отдельные особенности обозначаемого. Так, в паре глаголов гаснуть-тухнуть для слова гаснуть и его производных наиболее важным является указание на прекращение свечения, тогда как для тухнуть и его производных существенно также и прекращение горения.

ПРАКТИКА

Гасли последние звёзды (не светят больше). Потухли звезды (перестали вообще гореть!)  Вот и выбирает художник слова.
Понятие одно и то же, нет никакого противоречия между словами. А применение в речи разное, и построено оно на оттенках значения.
А это синонимы и какие синонимы? Можно предположить, что полные (запись через запятую). В словаре синонимов  свои правила.
ГАСНУТЬ. Словарь синонимов
Гаснуть (погаснуть, угаснуть), тухнуть (потухать), меркнуть, догорать, 
докуриться; замирать, отживать. Сейчас докурится фитиль в лампаде. Действ. 
форма: Гасить.


ГАСНУТЬ, -ну, -нешь; гас и гаснул, гасла, -ло; гаснувший и гасший; нсв. 1. 
(св. погаснуть и угаснуть; разг. загаснуть). **ПЕРЕСТАТЬ ГОРЕТЬ, СВЕТИТЬ; 
ТУХНУТЬ, ЗАТУХАТЬ.**. Огонёк то гас, то загорался снова. Гасли последние 
звёзды. День гаснет (о наступлении сумерек). 2. (св. погаснуть и 
загаснуть). Прекращаться, кончаться, исчезать. Надежда гаснет. Гаснет 
беседа, спор, ссора. Гаснет дарование, талант. 3. (св. угаснуть). Слабеть, 
терять силы; чахнуть. * Увы, Татьяна увядает; Бледнеет, гаснет и молчит! 
(Пушкин).


ТУХНУТЬ, -нет; тух и тухнул, тухла, -ло; нсв. (св. потухнуть и (разг.) 
затухнуть). 1. ПЕРЕСТАВАТЬ ГОРЕТЬ, СВЕТИТЬ; ГАСНУТЬ. Свечи тухнут. Звёзды 
тухнут. Солнце тухнет. 2. Ослабевать, уменьшаться. Тухнет талант. Тухнет 
острота восприятия. Тухнут чувства.

